# Nock, localhost, port, and redux-observable

Tags: testing, nock, redux-observable

I have a mock api setup with node/express

`http://localhost:8080/api/lyric/`

I'm using redux-observable to fetch the json:

```
const fetchLyricEpic = action$ =>
action$.ofType(FETCH_LYRIC)
  .mergeMap(action =>
    ajax.getJSON('/api/lyric')
      .map(response => fetchLyricSuccess(response))
      .catch(error => Observable.of(fetchLyricFail(error)))
  )
```

The problem is, when I test, I am getting an api error instead of 200 using `nock`:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  nock.disableNetConnect()
  nock.enableNetConnect('127.0.0.1:3000/')
})

afterEach(() => {
  nock.cleanAll()
  nock.enableNetConnect()
  epicMiddleware.replaceEpic(rootEpic)
})

test('it creates FETCH_SUCCESS when fetching the lyric has been done', () => {
  const payload = {
    status: 200,
    response: {
      'lyric': "Lyric"
    }
  }
  nock('127.0.0.1:3000/')
    .get('/api/lyric')
    .reply(200, payload, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

I'm trying to follow what I read in the nock docs and also in the issues list, however, my nock api call keeps failing.

```
Expected value to equal:
      [{"type": "FETCH_LYRIC"}, {"payload": {"lyric": "Lyric"}, "type": "FETCH_LYRIC_SUCCESS"}]
    Received:
      [{"type": "FETCH_LYRIC"}, {"payload": {}, "type": "FETCH_LYRIC_ERROR"}]
```

I should be receiving `FETCH_LYRIC_SUCCESS` instead I see:

```
[ { type: 'FETCH_LYRIC' },
        { type: 'FETCH_LYRIC_ERROR',
          payload:
           SyntaxError
               at XMLHttpRequest.open (<user>/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js:486:15)
               at XMLHttpRequest.tryCatcher (<user>/node_modules/rxjs/util/tryCatch.js:6:31)
               at AjaxSubscriber.Object.<anonymous>.AjaxSubscriber.send (<user>/node_modules/rxjs/observable/dom/AjaxObservable.js:208:56)
               at new AjaxSubscriber (<user>/node_modules/rxjs/observable/dom/AjaxObservable.js:180:14)
               at AjaxObservable.Object.<anonymous>.AjaxObservable._subscribe (<user>/node_modules/rxjs/observable/dom/AjaxObservable.js:115:16)
               at AjaxObservable.Object.<anonymous>.Observable._trySubscribe (<user>/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:57:25)
               at AjaxObservable.Object.<anonymous>.Observable.subscribe (<user>/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:45:27)
               at MapOperator.Object.<anonymous>.MapOperator.call (<user>/node_modules/rxjs/operator/map.js:54:23)
               at Observable.Object.<anonymous>.Observable.subscribe (<user>/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:42:22)
               at MapOperator.Object.<anonymous>.MapOperator.call (<user>/node_modules/rxjs/operator/map.js:54:23) } ]
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @jayphelps updated above ^^...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, it sounds identical to the issues described here: https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/1706

> I am working on a project that uses mocha with jsdom and enzyme to run our integration tests within a virtual dom in Node. Right now I am using node 6.9.2, and everything works fine. I tried using 7.4.0, however running the tests I got the error
>
> (nearly identical stack trace)

If indeed it is the same, some have reported this was an issue with Node 7.4.0 and that upgrading to 7.5.0 or higher solved the problem.

- > Ha! I just upgraded Node from 7.4.0 to the new 7.5.0 and the issue seems gone. Can you confirm? If so, this issue can be closed.
  >   https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/1706#issuecomment-276705307
- > 7.5.0 works for me!
  >   https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/1706#issuecomment-276774035

Comment: This...partially fixed it? Now I'm getting another error. Will probably mark this as ok.

Comment: @redconservatory if this solved that particular issue, consider marking it as accepted :) thank you!

Comment: It didn't but I just noticed that there is an issue https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/issues/144 which you can try to test with Observable. I am going to try that. Marking this as fixed now (sorry for the delay!)